# will a scheduled reminder be sent after the specified date, if it hasn't been sent before?

Tags: scheduled-reminders, cron-job

Suppose, on a running installation, I add a reminder to be sent 1 day after membership end date.

Will this reminder suddenly be sent to all members that expired eg. in the last year, because they didn't receive it earlier ? Or is it sent only to exactly those members that have a membership end date between 24 and 48 hours ago ?

Comment: A good question, I hope you find the answer and can document it.

Comment: I did not and worked around it. I have strong reason to believe it does indeed use either 24 hour or the date as a margin, and it wont be sent to all expired members in my example. But I'm still hoping for someone to show us some code, or a functional description in documentation, as proof.

Answer (score 1):

From memory scheduled reminders will only look into things within a 24hr window. So if you said 1 day after then the max it will go back is 2 days (1day + 24hrs). This was a while ago though, although I don't think things have changed.